# how to remove rows before a selected row

Tags: sed

I have a flat file data.txt in Linux/Centos server which contains a list of files e.g.

```
# cat data.txt
/home/user/data/1
/home/user/data/2
/home/user/data/3
/home/user/data/4
/home/user/data/5
/home/user/data/6
```

how can I remove from data.txt all rows before

```
/home/user/data/4
```

to receive this result

```
# cat data.txt
/home/user/data/4
/home/user/data/5
/home/user/data/6
```

Comment: `grep -A10000000000000000 /home/user/data/4 data.txt`

Comment: nice idea , thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sed -ne '/^\/home\/user\/data\/4$/,//p'`

Comment: This is better than my idea because it works on files with arbitrary lengths.

Comment: An alternative syntax: `sed -e '\|^/home/user/data/4$|,$!d'`